# Windows 10 BLE reconnecting program sometimes doesn't work showing some exception messages

Tags: uwp, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

all

I'm trying to implement a reconnecting procedure with Bluetooth Low Energy on Windows 10.

1. When Windows 10 detects a device disconnection via BLE, it will call the OnDisconnect callback.
2. In the OnDisconnect callback, I will try to scan BLE advertisement packets near a PC
   with a ReconnectManager class(which mentioned below)
3. When a ReconnectManager detects the packets that contains the manufacturer-specific byte pattern ,in this case it is "0x07 0xcc 0x22 0x11", Windows 10 tries to reconnect the device which emits the manufacturer-specific byte pattern.
4. But while it is trying to reconnect the device in the connectBLE function, sometimes
   the attempt fails, showing the following messages. Once these messages show up, it can never reconnect any BLE device....

```
   onecore\internal\sdk\inc\wil\opensource/wil/winrt.h(1594)\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll!00007FFA2993E3F4: (caller: 00007FFA2993722E) Exception(1) tid(5860) 8000FFFF Fatal Error.
0x00007FFA58114ED9 throws exception (In CPSApplication.exe): Microsoft C++ Exception: wil::ResultException (memory location 0x00000065DF97CC90)。
0x00007FFA58114ED9  (CPSApplication.exe): Microsoft C++ excption: [rethrow] (memory location 0x0000000000000000)。
onecoreuap\drivers\wdm\bluetooth\user\winrt\device\bluetoothledevice.cpp(1976)\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll!00007FFA29A477AD: (caller: 00007FFA29943C88) ReturnHr(1) tid(5860) 8000FFFF Fatal error.
    Msg:[onecore\internal\sdk\inc\wil\opensource/wil/winrt.h(1594)\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll!00007FFA2993E3F4: (caller: 00007FFA2993722E) Exception(1) tid(5860) 8000FFFF Fatal error
] 
onecoreuap\drivers\wdm\bluetooth\user\winrt\device\bluetoothledevice.cpp(1079)\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll!00007FFA29943CA7: (caller: 00007FFA29946800) ReturnHr(2) tid(5860) 8000FFFF Fatal error.
Exception throws 'System.Exception' (System.Private.CoreLib.dll)
```

I think that some racing problems might occur between BLE protocol stack and the connectBLE function,but I'm not sure some concrete solutions and workarounds.

My source code is below:

```
My code is what is displayed below:

        private async Task<Constants.ConnectionStatus> connectBLE(string deviceID)
        {
            BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothDev;
            List<GattDeviceService> services = new List<GattDeviceService>();
            List<Guid> srvGuids = new List<Guid>();

            srvGuids.Add(Constants.BluetoothChatServiceUuid);
            srvGuids.Add(Constants.BluetoothBatteryServiceUuid);

            try {
                    // Check permission of this device.
                    DeviceAccessStatus access = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromId(deviceID).CurrentStatus;
                    if (access == DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedBySystem || access == DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedByUser)
                    {
                        return Constants.ConnectionStatus.BTAccessError;
                    }
                    // Get BluetoothDevice structure.
                    bluetoothDev = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceID);
                    if (bluetoothDev == null)
                    {
                        return Constants.ConnectionStatus.BTNoDeviceError;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        // getting result for BLE using Gatt Service
                        foreach (Guid guid in srvGuids)
                        {
                            GattDeviceServicesResult BLEServices = await bluetoothDev.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(guid, BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
                            if (BLEServices.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success && BLEServices.Services.Count > 0)
                            {
                                services.AddRange(BLEServices.Services);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                services.Clear();
                                return Constants.ConnectionStatus.BTDiscoverError;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Received an Exception!");
                        services.Clear();
                        return Constants.ConnectionStatus.BTDiscoverError;
                    }

                    List<GattCharacteristic> characteristics = new List<GattCharacteristic>();

                    foreach (GattDeviceService srv in services)
                    {
                        // Ensure we have access to the device.
                        DeviceAccessStatus accessStatus = await srv.RequestAccessAsync();
                        if (accessStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed)
                        {
                            // BT_Code: Get all the child characteristics of a service. Use the cache mode to specify uncached characterstics only 
                            // and the new Async functions to get the characteristics of unpaired devices as well. 
                            GattCharacteristicsResult result = await srv.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                            if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                            {
                                characteristics.AddRange(result.Characteristics);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // On error, act as if there are no characteristics.
                                characteristics.Clear();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // On error, act as if there are no characteristics.
                            characteristics.Clear();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (characteristics.Count < 1)
                    {
                        return Constants.ConnectionStatus.BTServiceNameError;
                    }
            // reconnection has successfully finished!

                    return Constants.ConnectionStatus.Success;
                }
            catch (Exception ex) when ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80070490) // ERROR_ELEMENT_NOT_FOUND
            {
                return Constants.ConnectionStatus.BTElementNotFoundError;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80072740) // WSAEADDRINUSE
            {
                return Constants.ConnectionStatus.BTAddrInUseError;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return Constants.ConnectionStatus.BTExceptionError;
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }

        private async void OnDisconnect(object sender, string e)
        {
            CPSMsgHelper msg = (CPSMsgHelper)sender;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Disconnected (reason:" + e + ")");
            Constants.ConnectionStatus status = Constants.ConnectionStatus.BTNullError;

            bool isFound = false;

            string id = msg.DeviceID;

            Boolean stopCSV = StopCSVExport(id);
            if (stopCSV != true)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("StopCSVExport error...");
            }

            Model.Services.UpdateDevStatus.Update(id, DeviceInfo.DeviceStatus.DISCONNECT_TRY_TO_RECONNECT);
            OnPropertyChanged(msg, "DevStatusDisconnected");
            msg.OnDisconnect -= OnDisconnect;

            while (isFound == false)
            {
                Task<string> task = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    ReconnectManager mgr = new ReconnectManager(msg.DeviceID);
                    return mgr.Start();
                });
                task.Wait();
                if (task.Result != String.Empty)
                {
                    msg.DeviceID = task.Result;
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("Device has been found. ID = " + msg.DeviceID);
                status = await connectBLE(msg.DeviceID);
                Debug.WriteLine("Connection Status = " + status);
                if (status == Constants.ConnectionStatus.Success)
                {
                    Model.Services.UpdateDevStatus.Update(id, DeviceInfo.DeviceStatus.CONNECT);
                    OnPropertyChanged(msg, "DevStatusConnected");
                    isFound = true;
                    msg.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class ReconnectManager
    {
        private string bleID;
        private readonly ManualResetEvent mre;
        BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;
        private string retBLEID;

        public ReconnectManager(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                BluetoothLEManufacturerData manufacturerData = new BluetoothLEManufacturerData();
                manufacturerData.CompanyId = 0x07cc;
                DataWriter writer = new DataWriter();
                byte[] pattern = new byte[2];
                pattern[0] = 0x22;
                pattern[1] = 0x11;
                writer.WriteBytes(pattern);
                manufacturerData.Data = writer.DetachBuffer();
                mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                bleID = id;
                watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
                watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.InRangeThresholdInDBm = -70;
                watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeThresholdInDBm = -75;
                watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
                watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;
                watcher.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(manufacturerData);
                watcher.Received += watcher_received;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public string Start()
        {
            try
            {
                retBLEID = "";
                Debug.WriteLine("***Rescanning...***");
                mre.Reset();
                watcher.Start();
                mre.WaitOne();
                watcher.Stop();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception catched!" + ex.Message);
            }
            return retBLEID;
        }

        private async void watcher_received(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            ulong bleAddr = args.BluetoothAddress;
            try
            {
                BluetoothLEDevice dev = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(bleID);

                if (dev != null && dev.BluetoothAddress == bleAddr)
                {
                    retBLEID = dev.BluetoothDeviceId.Id;
                    mre.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error in watcher_received." + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards,

Yoshiteru Kageyama

Comment: Could you please collect Bluetooth logs for these exceptions using the [busiotools](https://github.com/microsoft/busiotools/blob/master/bluetooth/tracing/readme.md)

Comment: Thank you, Roy. I don't know the tools you mentioned. I'll give it a try to see if there are any problems in reconnecting BLE devices and Windows 10 PC.

Furthermore, I could come up with a different idea of maintaining the BLE connection using BLE Session Object. So, I'll show you another sample code on it.

Comment: Sure, please feel free to come back here.